# Why can't I access hash elements but still able to print/debug the object for the elements in my view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form where I have passed an object as a param using a hidden_field in a form.

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :activity, @activity %>
```

In my controllers show method I stop the params contents in a variable

```
@activity = params[:activity]
```

In my view I am able to access it. Below I used debug:

```
--- 'Activity:MouQj8XFEZ {"activityDescription"=>"Swimming in a pool", "activityName"=>"name a",
  "activityType"=>"swimming", "address"=>"022222 Pawson''s Road, Croydon, England,
  United Kingdom, ddd 2QD", "approvalStatus"=>false, "coordinates"=>#<Parse::GeoPoint:0x007f82dbace828
  @longitude=-0.09898502194827019, @latitude=51.3919513918931>
```

So I know there is something in the variable. Now when I try to access it like so:

```
Activity Name - <%= @activity["activityName"] %>

Activity Type - <%= @activity["activityType"] %>

Description - <%= @activity["activityDescription"] %>
```

I am presented with strings:

```
Activity Name - activityName

Activity Type - activityType 

Description - activityDescription
```

I have never come across this behaviour before.

Am I missing something?

Would appreciate some help.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: try printing `@activity.class`. Also, It does not make sense to send `params[:activity]` and then use that same param in view. Usually you send some params and use those params to fetch records from DB.

Comment: if `@activity.class` is a String, there you have problem spotted.

Comment: Are you certain those keys are strings, and not just being presented as strings when using debug?

Comment: I get back --- !ruby/class 'String'. This is a modeless application by the way. The records are stored on parse.com but I was trying to prevent the app from making extra calls by just passing the existing object around.

Comment: then you can pass the object as JSON, and parse it on client.

Comment: Since you use parse.com, you can store that object in localStorage or sessionStorage, no need to send that to your RoR server.

Comment: Guess I'm too used to the way I do things in iOS. I'm better off passing the string values over instead of the whole object.

Comment: You should not pass anything, read my comment.

Comment: can you paste the code you are using to get object from parse.com?

Comment: @juanpastas I ended up passing strings values over. Didn't want to complicate things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably consider having multiple `hidden_filed_tag`:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :activity_name, @activity.activityName %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :activity_type, @activity.activityType %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :activity_description, @activity.activityDescription %>
```

Then in controller use: `params["activityName"]`, `params["activityType"]`, and `params["activityDescription"]` to access each of them.

Actually, what you're trying to do is to have an object here in hidden field on HTML which is rendered:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :activity, @activity %>
```

NOTE: `@activity` is an object and that's the reason why you get that string and not the `params` as you expected.

Comment: I ended up doing this as I only need to pass a few strings over.